# Sklearn Neural Network train and test in two different steps - PYTHON

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have created a Neural Network using sklearn python:

```
 mlp=MLPClassifier()
 mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I run the code in python and the NN is trained.

Now I would predict something in a different stage and then without retrain the NN with this line:

```
 prediction=mlp.predict(X_test)
```

Basically, the fit and predict call, should be done in two different steps without retrain the NN each time for example in case I would validate a new set of data as:

```
 prediction2=mlp.predict(Z_test)
```

Comment: What have you done so far to accomplish your goal?

Comment: I compile my code in Pycharm, but compiling all together each time I retrain the NN

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pickle` to save a Python object to disk. So you would have a `train.py` which would `pickle` the MLP, and then a `test.py`, where you `unpickle` the object from local disk.

Comment: Could you please specify better? I'm new in Python and Pycharm. 
Basically, I should create two different py files, I run train.py first and test.py second, but where I should use pickle?
Thanks a lot

Comment: In your `train.py` file, you will train the algorithm, and at some point, arrive at an algorithm, lets call it `trained_MLP`, which you are happy with. Then, inside `train.py`, you would `pickle` trained_MLP (I dont remember the exact syntax at hand), and then at the top of `test.py` you would `unpickle` trained_MLP.

Comment: ok, perfect. I did it. But with a simple NN the file is correclty stored,
while with complex NN namely Cnet I obtained the error:

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded